# Rails: Determine if an object has a named route

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

In a Rails 3.1 app, I want to list a bunch of objects of variable class (from a polymorphic table) which I don't know in advance. For those that are resources with a named route, I'd like to use that route in a `link_to` call. Naive approach without checking if such a route exists (excuse the HAML):

```
%ul
- @objects.each do |object|
  %li= link_to object, url_for(object)
```

This will raise a `undefined method 'foo_path'` error if the object is an instance of class `Foo` which does not have a named route (for example because it's not defined as a resource). Is there an easy way (such as a simple method call) to determine the existence of a named route for an object or class?

What I would like to get is something like this:

```
%ul
- @objects.each do |object|
  %li= link_to_if object.has_route?, object, url_for(object)
```

Comment: Could you explain why you want to create a named route for that object? Is url_for outputting a generic URL for all objects because they share a common base type or what's wrong with the code you posted?

Comment: They don't necessarily share a common base type. I don't want to create the named route if it doesn't exist - I just want to check if it does.

Comment: Yes but from my experience url_for will simply generate the correct url for any given model object if there is a route present. 
Or do you have model objects without routes you'd like to filter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could just add a rescue to your link_to call if you don't want model objects without named routes to be generated or output some error message for them

```
%ul
- @objects.each do |object|
  %li= (link_to(object, url_for(object)) rescue "no link")
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm trying to avoid exactly that, since using exceptions for application logic is not ideal. Objects without named routes are not exceptions in my case but expected behaviour. But I guess I might just have to resort to this.

Comment: I also struggled with this in the beginning.. but at times it's better not to overthink things :) As long as things don't get out of hand complexity wise.. (I was also very wary since Exceptions in .NET are a very costly operation while in Ruby they seem to be lightning fast)

Answer (score 3):

Looking at the exact same problem. I don't like rescue for the same reason. I'm thinking

```
respond_to?(object.class.name.underscore + "_path")
```

This needs to be modified depending on nesting, subdomains, and STI; e.g., for my purpose I have:

```
respond_to?("ops_media_file_#{asset.class.base_class.name.underscore}_path")
```

and that seems to work pretty well.